# ListView doesnot return co-ordinate value of child views untill the screen is turned off and then turned on

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview to which I am setting an adapter in onCreate() method like this

```
SongListAdapter songListAdapter 
                   = new SongListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
all_songs.setAdapter(songListAdapter);
```

Here SongListAdapter is custom adapter. and all_songs is a Listview.

After that I try to fetch the co-ordinates of each of the child views inflated in the list by the method below in onCreate() but everytime I get all co-ordinates as zero. however if I do the same in onResume() I get the co-ordinates properly but to use them I first have to turn off screen then again turn it on and then I get the logs of co-ordinates . Please help I need the co-ordiantes without having to turn off and then turn on the screen.

```
int[] temp = new int[2];
float x,y,h,w;
View singleview=all_songs.getChildAt(i);
singleview.getLocationOnScreen(temp);
x = temp[0];
y = temp[1];
w =singleview.getWidth();
h = singleview.getHeight();
Log.d("faiz",String.valueOf(x)+" "+ String.valueOf(x+w)+"     "+String.valueOf(y)+" "+String.valueOf(y+h)+" "+String.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: What is zero? Where is `l` filled? Where is this code located?

Comment: Also, NEVER EVER use letter "l" as a variable name. Especially if this variable has virtually anything to do with numbers. It looks like a "1".

Comment: i  represents ith item in listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view layout is not complete in onCreate; you should add an onGlobalLayoutListener in onCreate to listen for this:

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = all_songs.getViewTreeObserver();
if(vto.isAlive()){
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // get coordinates
            // remove the listener
            vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Zero is same as singleview

Comment: thanks a lot Justin Powell it worked for me. just a small check needs to be added: 
add: if(vto.isAlive()) before calling                                                               vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);